# Keras loss function value doesn't decrease

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'm implementing an `MLP` with `Keras`, I notice that the loss function doesn't change during epochs.

I tried to varying learning rate and the weights initialization, but nothing changed.

Here's the code:

```
mlp = keras.models.Sequential()

# add input layer
mlp.add(
    keras.layers.Input(
        shape = (training_dataset.shape[1], )
    )
)
# add hidden layer
mlp.add(
    keras.layers.Dense(
        units=training_dataset.shape[1] - 500,
        input_shape = (training_dataset.shape[1] - 500,),
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None),
        bias_initializer='zeros',
        activation='relu')
    )

# add output layer
mlp.add(
    keras.layers.Dense(
        units=1,
        input_shape = (1, ),
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None),
        bias_initializer='zeros',
        activation='sigmoid')
    )

# define SGD optimizer
sgd_optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-2)

print('Compiling model...\n')

mlp.compile(
    optimizer=sgd_optimizer,
    loss=listnet_loss
)

mlp.summary() # print model settings

generator = DataGenerator(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels[0:5000], groups_id_count, [])

# Training
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  print('Start training')
  mlp.fit(generator, steps_per_epoch=len(training_dataset), 
                    epochs=50, verbose=1, workers=10, 
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    callbacks=[KendallTauHistory(generator)])
```

This is my loss function:

```
def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
  return -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(real_labels) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(predicted_labels)))
```

How could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, changing the optimizer the loss decreases during epochs.